# What is the impact if I truncate search_query table?

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.2.8

In my live site currently we have 2.1M records in the `search_query` table.
Due to this large number of records we are facing search slowness.

Whether it is advisable to truncate that table or remove the low priority search terms from that table?

Comment: What is the earliest search term?

Comment: less than 100 popularity 1.6M records are there

Comment: What about earliest as in the oldest to be last updated? `SELECT updated_at FROM search_query ORDER BY updated_at ASC`

Comment: 2016-04-18 23:12:28

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you clear out old entries rather than clear out lesser used terms.  Because that way you are not skewing your statistics.  You still want more recent lesser used terms as it still gives you an insight into popular/non-popular search terms on your website.

`DELETE FROM search_query WHERE updated_at < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)`